# Video upload on Amazon S3 in iphone application

Tags: ios, video, amazon-s3

I am uploading video to Amazon S3 from iphone application. Earlier it was uploading fine but now all of a sudden it has stopped uploading the video and crashes the app. Below is the code for video upload

```
    if(![ACCESS_KEY_ID isEqualToString:@"CHANGE ME"]
       && self.s3 == nil)
    {
        // Initial the S3 Client.
        self.s3 = [[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY] autorelease];
        self.s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];

    }


   NSString *videoName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titleTextField.text];
   NSString *trimmedString = [videoName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
   NSLog(@"name %@",trimmedString);

   S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:trimmedString
                                                          inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];



por.contentType = @"movie/mp4";


por.data= videoData;


S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];
```

Here is the crash log

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'AmazonServiceException', reason: '(null)' *** First throw call stack: (0x2f370f53 0x399db6af 0xb6119 0xc39b3 0xc2f4d 0x533b9 0x5366f 0x2fd53e27 0x3a002c1d 0x3a002b8f 0x3a000c90) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type AmazonServiceException

Comment: Seems everything to be good, try debugging and then provide us with the crash stack, hope we can help you.

Comment: can you plz edit your question and place the crash log there in the question itself.

Comment: @mAc added crash log in edit

Comment: This is not the whole crash log :(, this is the exception that u r getting. Well looking at the exception it is sure that u r getting null in return of some object. Try to debug where the object u r retrieving is getting null.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content length field and locally declaring the S3 client:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY]; //auto release deprecated, and not necessary with local declaration
s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];

//post full video
por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:generatedString inBucket:@"dormpicbucket"];
por.contentType = @"video/mp4";
por.data = capturedMovie;
por.delegate = self;
[por setDelegate:self];
por.contentLength = [capturedMovie length];
[s3 putObject:por];
```

Also make sure to debug this: `[Constants pictureBucket]` because it looks like youre using the sample/tutorial code from aws docs almost explicitly lol.